# Disable SQL Server Log Shipping to nonexistent destination

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, log-shipping

I am administering a SQL Server 2008 instance in a dev environment. At some point before I became an administrator, someone enabled log shipping from one of the databases on this dev instance to another dev instance. Now, the log shipping destination server no longer exists, and the source instance is creating hourly error log entries indicating the transaction log backups are severely out of sync. When I attempt to remove the destination server or disable log shipping for this database, I receive an error, since I cannot login to the nonexistent destination server.

Short of rebuilding the destination server, which is the last resort option, what can I do to disable log shipping without having to login to the destination server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to run two stored procedures to remove the setup of log shipping from the primary database [How to: Remove Log Shipping (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191297.aspx).  As the secondary doesn't exist you shouldn't need to perform step 2 & 4.

Comment: @AndrewE: if this did the trick, please mark this answer as the answer. You have a check mark near the voting signs.